# setting horizontal and vertical margins

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, margins

What is the method to set horizontal and vertical margins in a panel? (The same we have in html `style="margins:30px"`)

Comment: As others have mentioned, you should just use a Border (there is an EmptyBorder class in Swing to just do that). However, I would not recommend hard-coding the size of margins in a panel, especially using pixels (which size can change A LOT depending on the resolution of monitors). It is preferrable to use javax.swing.LayoutStyle to calculate the right margins. Or better, use a LayoutManager that does it for you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(int top, int left, int bottom, int right));`

And for more details you can read [the documentation about BorderFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html)

Comment: Why did you mark your own answer as 'correct' when kleopatra had provided the answer more than 2 days ago?

Comment: @  Andrew Thompson  this was the best answer i found recently,thus i updated the answers

Answer (score 6):

Don't know html, so just guessing on possible equivalents :-)

- to set some space between a component's bounding rectangle and its content, the property to set is its Border
- the spacing between the different components in a container is controlled by the LayoutManager (already mentioned). Depends on the concrete implementation how fine-grained that's configurable

Answer (score 0):

Use a [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) for your JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

That depends highly on the kind of Panel you are using.
If this refers to swing you could put a Gridbaglayout on it and specify Insets like in [this example](http://www.coderanch.com/t/333380/GUI/java/Adjust-border-margins-size-JPanel)

Answer (score 0):

for create basic "Gap" between JComponents by using LayoutManagers [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

[BorderLayout(int horizontalGap, int verticalGap)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#BorderLayout%28int,%20int%29)

[GridLayout(int rows, int cols, int hgap, int vgap)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

for most complex GUI you have to

1/ multiplayed JPanels (with different LayoutManager for each of  JPanel too)

2/ by using [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) (by multiplayed JPanels with different LayoutManegars for each JPanel ...)

3/ use some Custom LayoutManager